# Why are React props not updated in event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a functional component using the useEffect hook to subscribe to an external event and that external event is using a value in the components props. I dont understand why the component itself, when it renders, is using the updated prop value but my callback is using the original value.

I thought maybe I needed to change the second parameter of useEffect to specify props however this doesnt make any difference.

In the below example, the onSave callback is invoked and attempts to use the current value of *props.modelName* however, even though the component itself has an updated value the callback seems to only see the original value of that property.

Why is that? Does it have something to do with closure or am I missing something else?

```
useEffect(() => {
    EventBus.on(EventIds._designerSaveCommand, onSave);

    return () => {
      EventBus.remove(EventIds._designerSaveCommand, onSave);
    };
  }, [reactFlowInstance,props]);
```

And I have my event handler like this:

```
const onSave = () => {
    try {
      const object = reactFlowInstance?.toObject();

      if(object) {
        const exportedModel: IExportedModel = {
          modelName: props.modelName,  <---- This is not the current value in the component props
          model: object
        };

        const json = JSON.stringify(exportedModel);
        var blob = new Blob([json], { type: "application/json" });
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, `${props.modelName}.json`);
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      setMessage({text: e.message, type: MessageBarType.error});
    }
  };
```

Comment: Well I got this working using React.useRef, which I assume is the correct approach here, but will leave it open for someone to tell me something different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea by adding the prop to the dependency array. You also need to move the function `onSave()` to inside the hook. It will then be referring to the latest `modelName`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const onSave = () => {
    try {
      const object = reactFlowInstance?.toObject();
      if(object) {
        const exportedModel: IExportedModel = {
          modelName: modelName,
          model: object
        };

      const json = JSON.stringify(exportedModel);
        var blob = new Blob([json], { type: "application/json" });
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, `${modelName}.json`);
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      setMessage({text: e.message, type: MessageBarType.error});
    }
  };

  EventBus.on(EventIds._designerSaveCommand, onSave);

  return () => {
    EventBus.remove(EventIds._designerSaveCommand, onSave);
  };
}, [reactFlowInstance, modelName]);
```

If you don't like the `useEffect` so big, you can separate just the file logic to a new function, and call it inside the hook like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onSave = () => {
      saveFile(reactFlowInstance, modelName)
    };
    // ... handlers go here
  }, [reactFlowInstance, modelName]);
```